# Office Name Control PresenceEnabled is always false

Tags: javascript, wpf, internet-explorer-9, activex

I have a `WPF` app with a `WebBrowser` control, which loads an HTML file from the local disk. In the HTML file, I have javascript code to create an Office Lync Presence ActiveX Control (`Name.NameCtrl.1`) object which is used to display the contact card for some users.

The object gets created but the `PresenceEnabled` property for the Name Control is always **false**. Any ideas how I can work around this problem ?

I have Lync 2013 installed on the computer. The same code worked fine when I used Lync 2010.

My browser is **IE 9** and I have observed the same issue on IE 8 and IE 10 as well (currently targetting only IE).

**Javascript Code:**

```
try {
    var presenceObj = new window.ActiveXObject("Name.NameCtrl.1");
} catch (err) { }

function showLync(element) {
    try {
        // Works fine till this part. However, presenceObj.PresenceEnabled is false.
        presenceObj.ShowOOUI("somecalculatedalias", 0, $(element).offset().left, $(element).offset().top);
    } catch (err) {
        // goes into the catch block above with a "Permission denied" error (-2146828218)
    }
}
```

**More details**: 
I have added the MOTW (mark of the web) to my HTML page to make sure it shows up without the warning and I can see that the page does load in the correct zone. From page properties: `Local intranet | Protected Mode: Off`.

When I remove this MOTW, I get a the warning as expected saying "To Help protect your security, your web browser has restricted this file... (blah blah)". And when I allow the blocked content, the same code above works fine and I can see the Lync flyout from the ShowOOUI call.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas how I can work around this problem ?

Place the [AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers (APTCA) attribute](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839300) on the assembly.

Here are some other alternatives:

- [Security Zones](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174360)
- [Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628)

Answer (score 0):

The `PresenceEnabled` property is `false` if the control is used on a page that is not on the intranet or on a trusted site, or if a supported version of an instant messaging program such as Windows Live Messenger/Skype for Business is not running.